# StackOverFlowException when setting property

Tags: c#

I'm trying to using a conditional statement to check if a value equals something prior to setting it using a `setter`. I am returned a StackOverFlowException error. I am using another .cs file to execute the code for general practice.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Job_Classes
{
    class Workers
    {
        public string Name
        {
            get { return Name; }
            set
            {
                if (Name.CompareTo("Admin") == 0 || Name.CompareTo("Admin") == -1) //Just trying out comparison with the input.
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Name."); //To see if an invalid input that is not "Admin" fails.
                }
                else
                {
                    Name = value;
                    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
                }
            }
        }
        public Workers()
        {
            this.Name = null;
        }
        public Workers(string Name)
        {
            this.Name = Name;
        }
        public string Information()
        {
            return String.Format("Name: {0}", Name); 
        }             
    }
}
```

My execution code in another .cs is:

```
Workers Test = new Workers("John");
```

Comment: Read the exception trace; it would indicate the recurring calls..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is you re-assigning within the same `Property` which causes **recursion**:

```
       public string Name
    {
        get { return Name; }
        set
        {
            if (Name.CompareTo("Admin") == 0 || Name.CompareTo("Admin") == -1) //Just trying out comparison with the input.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Name."); //To see if an invalid input that is not "Admin" fails.
            }
            else
            {
                Name = value; //StackOverFlow here
                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
        }
    }
```

If you are validating it, you might wanna try a different approach.

**Solution #1** (Using separate variable for `Name` property)

```
private string name = "";
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
    set
    {
        if (value != null) //Check for null before validation (or it's up to you how to handle NULL value)
        {
            if (value.CompareTo("Admin") == 0 || value.CompareTo("Admin") == -1) //Just trying out comparison with the input.
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Name."); //To see if an invalid input that is not "Admin" fails.
            }
            else
            {
                name = value;
                Console.WriteLine("Done.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution #2** (Making `set` private and using separate `setter` method.

```
public string Name
{
    get;
    private set; //Making this private means you can still 
                    //access this setter within the class via `this.Name =`  (so be careful) 
}

/// <summary>
/// Defined a public setter which can be invoked outside
/// </summary>
/// <param name="value"></param>
public void SetName(string value)
{
    if (value != null) //Check for null before validation (or it's up to you how to handle NULL value)
    {
        if (value.CompareTo("Admin") == 0 || value.CompareTo("Admin") == -1) //Just trying out comparison with the input.
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Name."); //To see if an invalid input that is not "Admin" fails.
        }
        else
        {
            Name = value;
            Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        }
    }
}

public Workers(string Name)
{
    this.SetName(Name); //be careful making this.Name = Name or else no validation 
}

public Workers()
{
    this.SetName(null); //be careful with this.Name = null or else no validation
}
```

The disadvantage of the second approach is that inside the class `Workers` you should be careful when setting `this.Name` because it still accessible inside `Workers` even when set to `private`.

Comment: Stupid question but is `private string name = "";` just to serve as a placeholder to allow validation of `value`?

Comment: Yes in this case that would be it's practical use. In C# 1.0 this was the proper way of getting/setting property (a bit redundant as you have to declare property+place holder variable).

Answer (score 0):

When implementing a getter and/or setter function, you need to use a container variable for the value behind the property. This can be a simple variable or a more elaborate state represented by any combination of variables or constants.

A typical pattern might look like:

```
class a {
  private int i;
  public int I {
    get { return i; }
    set { i = value;}
  }
}
```

In your case that could be solved by defining a private class variable `name` and using that in your getter/setter functions.